R dplyr reframe warning vs error based on dataset
I have a dataset where I need to find the value above AND below a number (1.1 in this example). This is what I have done:
df1 <- data.frame(da=c(2.9245,2.8585,2.5225,2.0145,1.1715,0.5075,0.2645,0.0915), 
                  d2=c(2.912375,2.703375,2.502375,2.025375,1.110375,0.535375,0.243375,0.072375),
                  Blank...25=c(0.058,0.060,0.059,0.080,0.059,0.066,0.085,0.105), 
                  dilution=c(1:8))

titers_long2 <- df1 |>
  mutate(dilution = dilution) |>
  pivot_longer(-dilution)

titers2 <- titers_long2|>
  group_by(name) |>
  reframe(belowt = value[which(value == max(value[value<=1.1]))],
          abovet = value[which(value == min(value[value >=1.1]))],
          belowdil = dilution[which(value == max(value[value<=1.1]))],
          abovedil = dilution[which(value == min(value[value >=1.1]))]
  )

This works with the caveat that it gives me a warning for the names where the criteria are not met (Blank...25 in this case, where all values are <1.1).
However, the code behaves differently if I use a data frame with a different name for my Blank (in this case Blank...37), as follows:
df2 <- data.frame(da=c(2.9245,2.8585,2.5225,2.0145,1.1715,0.5075,0.2645,0.0915), 
                  d2=c(2.912375,2.703375,2.502375,2.025375,1.110375,0.535375,0.243375,0.072375),
                  Blank...37=c(0.054,0.060,0.057,0.085,0.078,0.067,0.063,0.085), 
                  dilution=c(1:8))

titers_long2 <- df2 |>
  mutate(dilution = dilution) |>
  pivot_longer(-dilution)

titers2 <- titers_long2|>
  group_by(name) |>
  reframe(belowt = value[which(value == max(value[value<=1.1]))],
          abovet = value[which(value == min(value[value >=1.1]))],
          belowdil = dilution[which(value == max(value[value<=1.1]))],
          abovedil = dilution[which(value == min(value[value >=1.1]))]
  )

Running the code with df2 gives me an error:
Error in `reframe()`:
! Can't recycle `abovet = value[which(value == min(value[value >= 1.1]))]`.
ℹ In group 1: `name = "Blank...37"`.
Caused by error:
! `abovet` must be size 2 or 1, not 0.
ℹ An earlier column had size 2.

Why does the code behave differently with df1 and df2 and how can I fix it?

It has nothing to do with the column names. You have different values in df1$Blank...25 and df2$Blank...37.

For df1$Blank...25 the values do not exceed 1.1, so the max(value[value <= 1.1]) exists for every group, but min(value[value >= 1.1]) does not exist. However, the code doesn't break because it likely still finds a value matching the condition in another column within the same group.
For df2$Blank...37, similar to df1, the values under "Blank...37" never exceed 1.1. This time, however, the absence of any value satisfying min(value[value >= 1.1]) results in an empty vector, which leads to an error because there is no valid value to use for abovet.

@ArnoneelSinha, thanks for the explanation. As you pointed out, in both cases the Blank columns do not have values for min(value[value >= 1.1]). The code does eliminate the Blank columns from the results, which to me means that it did not find a value. However, if the code is seeing a value on df1 but not on df2, then what is it seeing? And why is it not seeing it on df2? Is there a way to force the code and put an 'NA' on instances where it does not find a value that meets the criteria so that the code does not give an error?

This works for all data frames, reusing already calculated min/max values
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-dilution) %>% 
  summarize(bval = max(value[which(value <= 1.1)]), 
            aval = min(value[which(value > 1.1)]), 
            bdil = max(dilution[bval == value]), 
            adil = min(dilution[aval == value]), .by = name) %>% 
  suppressWarnings()
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  name        bval   aval  bdil  adil
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 da         0.507   1.17     6     5
2 d2         0.535   1.11     6     5
3 Blank...25 0.105 Inf        8   Inf

df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-dilution) %>% 
  summarize(bval = max(value[which(value <= 1.1)]), 
            aval = min(value[which(value > 1.1)]), 
            bdil = max(dilution[bval == value]), 
            adil = min(dilution[aval == value]), .by = name) %>% 
  suppressWarnings()
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  name        bval   aval  bdil  adil
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 da         0.507   1.17     6     5
2 d2         0.535   1.11     6     5
3 Blank...37 0.085 Inf        8   Inf

Using sort instead of max avoids warnings and nicely puts NA but is a bit slower on huge data sets.
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-dilution) %>% 
  summarize(bval = last(sort(value[which(value <= 1.1)])), 
            aval = first(sort(value[which(value > 1.1)])), 
            bdil = last(sort(dilution[bval == value])), 
            adil = first(sort(dilution[aval == value])), .by = name)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  name        bval  aval  bdil  adil
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1 da         0.507  1.17     6     5
2 d2         0.535  1.11     6     5
3 Blank...25 0.105 NA        8    NA


Thanks Andre, the output you show is what I need but when I use the code you provided it gives me an error: "Error in summarize(., bval = max(value[which(value <= 1.1)]), aval = min(value[which(value >  : argument "by" is missing, with no default". I do not understand why since ".by = name" is there. Also for my learning, why does it give a NA for df1 but an Inf for df2?

@AC_06 have you updated dplyr in a while? Please update it! install.packages('tidyverse')

What Mark said, because .by was introduced a while ago in dplyr 1.1.0, I think. You can still use the group_by(name) way though. I used max() in the first two examples but showed using sort() as an alternative on df1, which generates NA instead of Inf.

My dplyr was updated. I did restart R and loaded only tidyverse and the code works! Another package must have interfered with .by. Thank you for your help!
